# Multiple transitions for Twitter bootstrap .transition?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less, css-transitions

I am wanting to animate two properties in Bootstrap v2.1.0,

The `opacity` and the `margin`.

I have tried:

`.transition(opacity 0.5s, margin 0.25s);`: No output
`.transition('opacity 0.5s, margin 0.25s');`: Invalid CSS output
`.transition(opacity 0.5s); .transition(margin 0.25s);`: Margin overrides opacity.

Note that I am using [lessphp](http://leafo.net/lessphp/) so solutions that use the JavaScript regex will not work.

I know I could copy the mixin and modify it to accept two parameters as well, but that just seems hacky, surely there is a better way?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

### Two Options (Depending on version of LESS)

**LESS (1.3.3+)**

The [less2css.org](http://less2css.org/) shows this works with LESS 1.3.2 on experimentation, but the [issue documentation](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/1211) seems to indicate this is [a 1.4 release addition](https://github.com/less/less.js/commit/c583acede0d0e2449582167e8b28922ee69f2cdd).

Whenever it became effective, at some point, the semicolon was introduced as a possible variable separator in parametric mixins while still allowing commas. The presence of a `;` causes commas to be viewed *not* as separating variables, but rather as part of the *value* of the variable itself (a comma separated list). This then allows (to [quote the site](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-parametric-feature-mixins-with-multiple-parameters)) us to use a "dummy semicolon to create mixin call with one argument containing comma separated css list."

Therefore the following works to produce the same output as above ***without the escaped string*** (**NOTE** the "dummy" semicolon put at the end of the variable entry, right *before* the closing parenthesis of the parametric mixin call):

```
.transition(opacity 0.5s, margin 0.25s;);
                                      |
                                semicolon here
```

**LESS (pre 1.3.3, but also works in later versions)**

Do a string interpolation (`~`) for the passed in variables:

```
.transition(~"opacity 0.5s, margin 0.25s");
```

**Both solutions output**:

```
-webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s, margin 0.25s;
-moz-transition: opacity 0.5s, margin 0.25s;
-o-transition: opacity 0.5s, margin 0.25s;
transition: opacity 0.5s, margin 0.25s;
```